# Show that $\rho(A,B)=P(A\triangle B)$ is a pseudo-metric

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Prove that the function $$\rho(A,B)=P(A\triangle B)$$ is a pseudo-metric: $\rho(A,B)\geq 0$ with equality if and only if $P(A\triangle B)=0$, $\rho(A,B)=\rho(B,A)$ and $\rho(A,C)\leq \rho(A,B)+\rho(B,C)$ for all $A,B,C$ So far I managed to show this:$$\rho(A,B)=P(A\triangle B)=P(A/B\cup B/A)$$$$\rho(B,A)=P(B\triangle A)=P(B/A\cup A/B)$$ I dont really know how to proceed and what to do. It seems everything is given, I mean that the definition of a pseudo-metric is stated in the problem. I a little bit confused with the statement of the problem.

Comment: Have you seen what a metric / norm is?

Comment: No, this question is from probability theory and it wasnt covered in the class. So I assume there is easy way to answer this but it is not coming to my head.

Comment: It is not "hard", but it will definitely feel out of place if you don't even know what a norm is. You will need the fact that $$ A\Delta B = [A\Delta C] \Delta [C\Delta B] $$

Comment: A metric/norm is a distance right?

Comment: Informally, yes. But there is a precise definition for what it means, which are generalised from properties of the absolute value function on $\Bbb R$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: The problem is that I am economics student and I have to take this class with mathematics majors. So they assume that everyone is math major.

Comment: Perhaps that is a problem, but may I suggest focusing at the task at hand? There are 3 things to check: in the order you have said them: [1] the function called $\rho$ needs to be non-negative; [2] it needs to be symmetric; [3] it needs to satisfy the 'triangle inequality'. Can you verify [1]?

Comment: $P$ is probability

Comment: It may feel that way but I promise that some of the math students are feeling that way too.

Comment: not $P$, $\rho$. Is it true that $\rho(A,B) ≥ 0 $ for every $A,B$?

Comment: So I need to check three cases: $A=B$, $A⊆B$ and $B⊆A$ right?

Comment: Its much simpler. The fact that $P$ satisfies a similar property immediately gives what we want.

Comment: Oh, I see it is probability and probability is non-negative. Does my symmetry proof look right?

Comment: @Don, yes,  Symmetry of $\rho$ follows from symmetry of $\Delta$.  That leaves the triangle inequality.

Comment: For triangle inequality i was suggested to use norm but dont know how to come up with that inequality proof

Comment: @Don, Use $X\Delta Y = (X\cup Y)\cap(X^\complement \cup Y^\complement) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that $\rho(A,B) \geq 0$ because $P$ is a probability measure and thus $P(A\Delta B)\geq 0$.

Likewise since the symmetric difference is the empty set if and only if the sets are equal, therefore $\rho(A,B)=0 \iff A=B$.

You have shown that symmetry of $\rho$ follows from the symmetry of symmetric difference; via $\rho(A,B) = P(A\Delta B) = P(B\Delta A) = \rho (B, A)$

---

Now then, does the triangle inequality hold: $\rho(A,C)\leq \rho(A,B)+\rho(B, C)$ for all events $A,B,C$ in the space?

Take the LHS and RHS statements, expand into their probability forms and compare.

> $$\begin{align}\rho(A, C) & = P(A\Delta C) \\[1ex] & = P\big((A\cap C^\complement)\cup(C\cap A^\complement)\big) \\[1ex] & = P\big((A\cup C)\cap(A^\complement\cup C^\complement)\big) \\[2ex] \rho(A,B)+\rho(B,C) & = P(A\cap B^\complement)+P(B\cap A^\complement)+P(B\cap C^\complement)+P(C\cap B^\complement) \\[1ex] & = P\Big(\big((A\cup C)\cap B^\complement\big)\cup\big((A^\complement\cup C^\complement)\cap B\big)\Big)\\ & = P\big( (A\cup C\cup B)\cap(A^\complement \cup C^\complement \cup B^\complement)\big) \end{align}$$

Comment: I see now thanks.